# Nested lambda capture of variable gives incorrect warning

Tags: c++, lambda, clang, c++20, compiler-warnings

I'm using a nested lambda to walk through some data.
The outer lambda does some processing and then calls the inner lambda.

I get the following warning:

```
x86-64 clang 13.0.1 - 2629ms (104630B) ~1800 lines filtered

    Output of x86-64 clang 13.0.1 (Compiler #1)

<source>:9:34: warning: class '' does not declare any constructor to initialize its non-modifiable members
    const auto PickVarAtRandom = [&]<bool SATvar> {
                                 ^
<source>:9:34: note: in instantiation of member class '' requested here
<source>:18:41: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'main()::(anonymous class)::operator()<true>' requested here
    const auto result = doPick.template operator()<true>();
                                        ^
<source>:10:13: note: reference member '' will never be initialized
        if (Length > 50) { printf("hallo"); return false; }
```

The code uses a nested lambda call. The following code will reproduce the issue in [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/753o18xqP).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    const auto Length = rand() % 2;

    //warning: class '' does not declare a constructor ...
    //                           V
    const auto PickVarAtRandom = [&]<bool SATvar> {
        if (Length > 0) { printf("one  %i", Length); return false; }
        else            { printf("zero %i", Length); }
        return true;
    };

    const auto doPick = [&]<bool SATvar>() {
        return PickVarAtRandom.template operator()<SATvar>();
    };

    const auto result = doPick.template operator()<true>();
}
```

The error goes away if just use a single lambda:

```
//no warning
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const auto Length = rand() % 100;

    const auto PickVarAtRandom = [&]<bool SATvar> {
        if (Length > 50) { printf("hallo"); return false; }
        return true;
    };

 
    const auto result = PickVarAtRandom.template operator()<true>();
}
```

I'm using clang 14 on MacOS, but in order to reproduce the warning in godbolt I need to select clang 13.

```
clang++ --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
```

Why do I get this warning with nested lambdas?
Can I suppress the warning?
Or is there a way to get rid of the warning whilst still using nested lambdas?

Comment: clang 14 and 15 will compile so most likely a bug.  I can see the optimizer being clever and `Length` not actually getting captured since it is a constant expression.  That could then cause the part the builds the constructor to issue a broken constructor.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Ha, didn't even notice that. Well at least I know I can safely update the links :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a compiler bug that was fixed in this commit:
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/f7007c570a216c0fa87b863733a1011bdb2ff9ca.

As you can see, the commit is in clang 14, specifically between the tags `llvmorg-14.0.0-rc2` and `llvmorg-14.0.0-rc3`. So it makes sense that the warning does not appear on godbolt with clang 14 but does with clang 13, and I guess the version on your machine is not the most recent clang 14.

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any flag attached to this warning. If you cannot upgrade, I think the only way to suppress it in code is with a pragma for `-Weverything`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const auto Length = rand() % 2;

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Weverything"
    const auto PickVarAtRandom = [&]<bool SATvar> {
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
        if (Length > 0) { printf("one  %i", Length); return false; }
        else            { printf("zero %i", Length); }
        return true;
    };

    const auto doPick = [&]<bool SATvar>() {
        return PickVarAtRandom.template operator()<SATvar>();
    };

    const auto result = doPick.template operator()<true>();
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Ts7ovqh8s)

You can of course compile with `-Wno-everything` or `-w`, but that's a bad idea in general.

As for why you get this warning... my guess from looking at the commit is that the additional condition `cast<CXXRecordDecl>(D)->getTemplateDepth() > TemplateArgs.getNumRetainedOuterLevels()` makes some part of clang correctly treat `PickVarAtRandom` as local, which somehow solves the warning. Perhaps you can find more info [in here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D99134).

Comment: Nice findings! Nice answer 

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bug from clang, as neither gcc nor a more recent version (>13) of clang gives this warning with `-std=c++20`.

> Can I suppress the warning?

Yes.

See on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/gEADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/qRJKY4CIWGRLDFxZgF2mA5pQgRMxAQZPn4VmPb5DLX1BIUR0bHxtnUNTVkVwz2hfSUD5QCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CYbbsgKBOi0eFGH2CYaAIKb27uYB0cnZ07Xtw/336EEexYTFCEDmBwA7FZ7nsYXs0AxTnsmF4iHsgoxgAQEK8ACJ7YiGdCgg5mACsezMhyhPzusL2AHp6QB3eoMUKgOEGBQKPZgDh8vboVCYHkMVAArA7eovJhwgSnYheBwkPYAOnV3zpjLpOt1ep1ADVNbD4YjkajlHhkABrA31O4EABKhNQLFxB1JVjMADYTKScYc3FFUJ49kI7gAVABu9WuEOp%2BrwVD2EHRRixr2wew0YJMkL2CWI/yoEHMZgELxJpLwZdIaIxWLmVPxmAIywYeyoYiUzbzAeheraSn1dLzFgLRcEJbLAC9YqgqzXynW05iEE2NuO%2B8bdcRW%2B29gRFZgqTuIQHN98z6aAeaF0LLTb3X6vb7/YHg6Hw9HYxtsMSxzPOk9zbYgO0fW17SdF0WFVAhMBYBIDHgvZUASWImCIYhQUDb8Y2Ia4cMvAcYW3YiaTpG8kRRBc9wULxaABQ48QfK1rTghCkMwl40IwrCiLcI8vBPP8iITWEQIPOiGIIU9fnBHEOAWWhOFJXg/A4LRSFQTg3Gsaw9gUJYVheTYeFIAhNCUhZrRASRwVVDZvQADkkMwuA0UkfQ2LhSXBUl9E4SR1Ks7TOF4BQQA0CyrIWOBYBgRAUFdBI6FichKDQRC0riKUjCkDRopoRjYkiiAolCqJQnqABPThzKythBAAeQYWg6s03gsCBIxxE60h8D3aooxFULMFUKoUTWcz/jaUKLiiAliBqjwsFCo88BYeqlL4AxgAUA08EwJlmvQjTzP4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdR%2Bt0Lh9EMYx9MsfRLkiyAFjQjpIo4ABaZqzD2EGAHUxFoSGofGo9ZWh2JiBVEHTnQZjTEsawzC0ypqmcCBXFGPw3uCKZilKPRclSAQydp5J6YYXpqYGN7CY6LoRk8Zo9C5moJjZ/o4k5iZGfF7oRZmMWFiM5ZVj0I9MGmnaVI4NTSA0rSdI4VRnO9EHvUkTkPr2KRVQ0K2Uz03Hvr2XBCBVMy6w8bL6GIEkfLmXhLM6uYbJALzVW9Hy/OcgBOeynNcslAo4YLSC20lop13g9YiqKYoD0h4qSrLUs9jKIELnKQGALhl2K%2BDiDKir%2Bqq5hlu20hGsYAhWva0Luo%2BvqtMGqpHBG4GtPGyb4Nb2aNa0halpWjA1i0jatu4HaqD2g6jpOs7W8u4RRHEO798etRQt0AIDCMFAvpsBa/tBbSEiBzgwYh6HYfhxGCS/4g0a9jGZxsa33xhFNoQ80guAYO4PmWQKbQJljTN6dMOiSxyMzDoiCOa2HAUTToEtYHkxwe0IW0sqaiwFgQzIRDThkKKBQrg8tjJKzeirNWylVIhX6nrA2RsTZ7GAMgZAFszCqghhAO2XobCO3wFhb2b09juyLrEb2ZhfY5y0IHUgCBMBMCwHER%2BGsk4pzTqFTOths7%2B00UHEOYdfLgijjHFybkAoaw2Fw3W4UNHWQTmYDxGcvFWJ8SNOukDJBAA%3D%3D).